# Switch from VBA to VB.net - change Array of Arrays (variant) to?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba

I'm trying to switch to vb.net an old vba code.

Into the VBA code I have an Array of Arrays to store (into each sub-array) a number (min = 3 max = 8) and some strings (equals to number stored into the sub-array).

I'm undecided about the type of object to use instead of the array of arrays.

The array contains the number of columns and their names for 6 tables. It would be useful if I could call each group of table data using the table name.

I was thinking about using a dictionary for each sub-array, but I hope  in a better suggestion.

The VBA Array is like this:

```
MT = Array( _
Array(8, "ColA1", "ColA2", "ColA3", "ColA4", "ColA5", "ColA6", "ColA7", "ColA8"), _
Array(3, "ColB1", "ColB2", "ColB3"), _
Array(4, "ColC1", "ColC2", "ColC3", "ColC4"), _
Array(6, "ColD1", "ColD2", "ColD3", "ColD4", "ColD5", "ColD6"), _
Array(7, "ColE1", "ColE2", "ColE3", "ColE4", "ColE5", "ColE6", "ColE7"), _
Array(5, "ColF1", "ColF2", "ColF3", "ColF4", "ColF5"))
```

Comment: If you just do a straight conversion you wont get much benefit from things like Classes, Lists and so forth.  That whole thing looks like it could be one `Dictionary(of Integer, List(Of String))`  but the value could possibly be a class (no idea what the data represents).

Comment: @Plutonix You gave me a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on what you are trying to preserve.

If you want to be able to access MT in a similar fashion this might work for you:

```
Class mta
    Public elem() As String
    Default Property x(indx As Integer) As String
        Get
            Return elem(indx)
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ' na
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim mt As New List(Of mta)
    Dim m As New mta
    m.elem = {8, "ColA1", "ColA2", "ColA3", "ColA4", "ColA5", "ColA6", "ColA7", "ColA8"}
    mt.add(m)
    m.elem = {3, "ColB1", "ColB2", "ColB3"}
    mt.Add(m)
    ' etc
    Debug.Print(mt(1)(1))
End Sub
```

This would create a ragged array with the first element containing a count. You could modify the default Get() to return your version of Null to avoid errors. Of course the Class mta could be redesigned to Get/Set the count differently.

The initialization is significantly different.

Comment: Thanks, this way I'll be able to reuse loops of the old code. ;)

Comment: Ooops: How can I loop items into each m? How can I count them? `For x = 0 to mt.count` works but `For y = 0 to mt(x).count` doesn't

Comment: Another question: Why should I prefer to use this class instead of a jagged array?

Comment: I don't know how to create a "jagged array." You can use a 2d array with the count in the first column as you had but just have a bunch of unused cells. RE: Count - you can add a Count property to the class that returns the value you need. If you keep the data structure the same just return the 0th element in the array which by convention is the count.